# Updating progress bar dynamically issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get my page's progress bar to update dynamically. I got that part to work but I am having issues with it. Firstly, the count keeps increasing as I keep pressing the button. So, how can I stop it from happening more than one for that particular field when I have the same update button on both of them? On my website, the forms are in different tabs which is why I am using the same update button. Secondly, if i fill out all the input's... the counter increases by `35` instead of `15` or `20`. Is there a solution possible without me having to have different update buttons for each?

HTML:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" data-values="40">0</div>
</div>
<form method="post" action="#" class="basicInfo">
  <label>Title:</label>
  <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control required" />
  <br/>
  <label>Price:</label>
  <input type="number" id="price" class="form-control required" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="btn" />
</form>
<br />
<form method="post" action="#" class="descriptionInfo">
  <label>Description:</label>
  <input type="text" id="description" class="form-control required" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="btn" />
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var percentage = 10;
  $("[name='submit']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#title").val().length > 0 && $("#price").val() > 0) {
      percentage += 20;
      $(".progress-bar").css("width", percentage + "%");
      $(".progress-bar").text(percentage + "%");
    }
    if ($("#description").val().length > 0) {
      percentage += 15;
      $(".progress-bar").css("width", percentage + "%");
      $(".progress-bar").text(percentage + "%");
    }

  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L0z0v858/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cumulative issue. 
Instead of `adding += somevalue` you shoud divide the percentage by items:

When a field is updated you set the field value:`field1_value = 33.3;` and update the percentage.

```
percentage = field1_value + field2_value + field3_value
```

Edit: [Added jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/L0z0v858/3/)
Be sure all your form values added give 100 in total. :D

Comment: I understand your logic but i m having trouble implementing it... Please check http://jsfiddle.net/L0z0v858/2/. Would it be possible for you to post a demo?

Comment: Quick Demo http://jsfiddle.net/L0z0v858/4/ this will use the class name to count how many inputs are required to divide between 100, this will calculate the % I'm using the on input event to trigger a for each loop to then check if the inputs are empty or = to 0 to calculate the % of progress. Reason for the changes are if you want/need to add more inputs to the form the script will calculate the rest for you so no changes should be needed to the source code. *I would advise adding a min="0" attribute to your number input*